# Issues Linking ObjC Library using Xamarin

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've been working on binding my first ObjC library ([SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/)) for the past few days. I've got it all building and compiling but I'm unable to get it running when referenced by another project.

My code for the binding can be found here: https://github.com/jamesmundy/SVGKit.Xamarin

When run, the following error is displayed:

> Could not create an native instance of the type
>   'SVGKitBindings.SVGKImageView': the native class hasn't been loaded.
>   It is possible to ignore this condition by setting
>   ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.

I've checked the static library I'm using and it supports the following platforms:

> Architectures in the fat file: libSVGKit-iOS.1.2.0.a are: armv7 i386
>   x86_64 arm64

I believe this is all I need.

My linker file is as follows:

> [assembly: LinkWith ("libSVGKit-iOS.1.2.0.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 |
>   LinkTarget.Simulator, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]

**Do I have to configure the project that I'm using this binding in differently? Any help getting the native library to load is much appreciated.**

**Update 1:** Thanks to a suggestion I tried editing the Linker file to support the same platforms as the static library, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. The file is now as follows:

> [assembly: LinkWith ("libSVGKit-iOS.1.2.0.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 |
>   LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.Arm64 | LinkTarget.Simulator64,
>   SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]

I also tried the code on all the emulators, but still had no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem after having identified a few issues with my code and the project.

- The Linker.cs file was not actually building with the project. Although it was in the solution it wasn't being compiled and therefore the important information it contained to link the libraries together was missing.
- SVGKit uses several framework. I was not referencing these in the linker file and there were some other linkerflags needed. When I had solved this issue the file looked like this:

> [assembly: LinkWith ("libSVGKit-iOS.1.2.0.a",     LinkTarget.ArmV7 |
>   LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.Arm64 | LinkTarget.Simulator64, 
>     SmartLink = true,   Frameworks="QuartzCore CoreText CoreGraphics
>   CoreImage UIKit",     LinkerFlags="-lxml2 -ObjC",     ForceLoad = true)]

Comment: how did you know this wasn't being compiled? Have you managed to link any Xamarin iOS project to a native iOS framework, especially anything that uses AFNetworking or any other framework of it's own?

Comment: Hi @JayKannan sorry, this was so long ago I'm struggling to remember my exact steps. 
I was also on the Xamarin forums a lot:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30921/issues-linking-svgkit-objc-library

I believe I have linked libraries that used frameworks, thoough not AFNetworking.

Comment: do you have any sample code to share? theres hardly any on the internet. I can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong! I can't seem to get access to the bound class at all!

Comment: Hard to see exactly what the issue is but maybe some of my examples will help? Every project I have bound is on my GitHub page?https://github.com/jamesmundy?tab=repositories

Comment: Have you managed to bind a native framework directly? there are samples, but I have no idea why I can;'t bind my own in the exact same way

Comment: AFNetworking should already been included in Xamarin? This is a framework that has been bound with Xamarin too: https://github.com/joeisapro/MonoTouch.Fabric

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking at that now

Answer (score 1):

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libSVGKit-iOS.1.2.0.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true)]
```

That might not be your (only) issue but it's not correct. Your `LinkTarget` should be matching the architecture supported by the static library. IOW you are missing `Arm64` and `Simulator64`.

Also try to execute your application on different simulators (32 bits, like iPhone 4S, and 64bits like iPhone 5S) or devices (again 32 vs 64 bits). That will tell you if it's a general or architecture-specific issue (and you should update your question with those extra bits of information).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this.

Comment: Updated the question, no change unfortunately.